# Prove that $DG+HE=GH$ for the given figure.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, projective-geometry, geometric-transformation

[image]

What I could gather:

$$\measuredangle ODB=\measuredangle OFC=\measuredangle OEC =90 \text{ degrees}$$
$$OD=OF=OE=r$$
$$\measuredangle ODE=\measuredangle OED$$
$$\measuredangle DOE=2\measuredangle DME$$

[image]

Comment: Well, I have solution with use of projective transformations... If anyone is interested I can write it down.

Comment: @john nobody yes please, I am curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

This is a pure trigonometry solution.

Let
$|BC|=a$, $|AC|=b$, $|AB|=c$,
$\angle BAC=\alpha$, 
radius of excircle
$|O_aM|=r_a$,
$S$ is the area 
and $\rho=\tfrac12(a+b+c)$
is a semiperimeter
of $\triangle ABC$.

Let's prove a slightly stronger statement
than $|DG|+|EH|=|GH|$, namely that

\begin{align}
|DG|&=|LH|,\quad |GL|=|EH|
.
\end{align}

\begin{align}
|AM|&=r_a\,\frac{1+\sin\tfrac\alpha2}{\sin\tfrac\alpha2}
,\quad
|AL|=r_a\,\frac{\cos^2\tfrac\alpha2}{\sin\tfrac\alpha2}
,\\
|AK|&=c\,\cos\tfrac\alpha2
,\quad
|AN|=b\,\cos\tfrac\alpha2
,\quad
|LM|=r_a\,(1+\sin\tfrac\alpha2)
,\\
|KM|&=r_a\,\frac{1+\sin\tfrac\alpha2}{\sin\tfrac\alpha2}
-c\,\cos\tfrac\alpha2
,\\
|NM|&=r_a\,\frac{1+\sin\tfrac\alpha2}{\sin\tfrac\alpha2}
-b\,\cos\tfrac\alpha2
,\\
|BK|&=c\,\sin\tfrac\alpha2
,\quad
|CN|=b\,\sin\tfrac\alpha2
,\\
|DL|&=|LE|=r_a\,\cos\tfrac\alpha2
,\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
|GL|&=\frac{|LM|\,|BK|}{|KM|}
=\frac{c\,r_a\,(1+\sin\tfrac\alpha2)\,\sin\tfrac\alpha2}
{r_a\,\frac{1+\sin\tfrac\alpha2}{\sin\tfrac\alpha2}
 -c\,\cos\tfrac\alpha2}
,\\
|HL|&=\frac{|LM|\,|CN|}{|NM|}
=
\frac{b\,r_a\,(1+\sin\tfrac\alpha2)\,\sin\tfrac\alpha2}
{r_a\,\frac{1+\sin\tfrac\alpha2}{\sin\tfrac\alpha2}
 -b\,\cos\tfrac\alpha2}
,\\
|EH|&=r_a\,\cos\tfrac\alpha2
-
\frac{b\,r_a\,(1+\sin\tfrac\alpha2)\,\sin\tfrac\alpha2}
{r_a\,\frac{1+\sin\tfrac\alpha2}{\sin\tfrac\alpha2}
 -b\,\cos\tfrac\alpha2}
\end{align}

Now we just need to prove that $|GL|=|EH|$ is an identity:

\begin{align}
\frac{c\,(1+\sin\tfrac\alpha2)\,\sin\tfrac\alpha2}
{r_a\,\frac{1+\sin\tfrac\alpha2}{\sin\tfrac\alpha2}
 -c\,\cos\tfrac\alpha2}
=
\cos\tfrac\alpha2
-
\frac{b\,(1+\sin\tfrac\alpha2)\,\sin\tfrac\alpha2}
{r_a\,\frac{1+\sin\tfrac\alpha2}{\sin\tfrac\alpha2}
 -b\,\cos\tfrac\alpha2}
\tag{1}\label{1},\\
\frac{c\,(1+\sin\tfrac\alpha2)\,\sin\tfrac\alpha2}
{r_a\,\frac{1+\sin\tfrac\alpha2}{\sin\tfrac\alpha2}
 -c\,\frac{1-\sin^2\tfrac\alpha2}{\cos\tfrac\alpha2}}
=
\cos\tfrac\alpha2
-
\frac{b\,(1+\sin\tfrac\alpha2)\,\sin\tfrac\alpha2}
{r_a\,\frac{1+\sin\tfrac\alpha2}{\sin\tfrac\alpha2}
 -b\,\frac{1-\sin^2\tfrac\alpha2}{\cos\tfrac\alpha2}}
\tag{2}\label{2},\\
\frac{c\,\sin\tfrac\alpha2}
{\frac{r_a}{\sin\tfrac\alpha2}
 -c\,\frac{1-\sin\tfrac\alpha2}{\cos\tfrac\alpha2}}
=
\cos\tfrac\alpha2
-
\frac{b\,\sin\tfrac\alpha2}
{\frac{r_a}{\sin\tfrac\alpha2}
 -b\,\frac{1-\sin\tfrac\alpha2}{\cos\tfrac\alpha2}}
\tag{3}\label{3},\\
\frac{c\,\sin^2\tfrac\alpha2}
{r_a\,\cos\tfrac\alpha2
 -c\,(1-\sin\tfrac\alpha2)\,\sin\tfrac\alpha2}
=
1
-
\frac{b\,\sin^2\tfrac\alpha2}
{r_a\,\cos\tfrac\alpha2
 -b\,(1-\sin\tfrac\alpha2)\,\sin\tfrac\alpha2}
\tag{4}\label{4},\\
\frac{\sin^2\tfrac\alpha2}
{\frac{r_a}{c}\,\cos\tfrac\alpha2
 -(1-\sin\tfrac\alpha2)\,\sin\tfrac\alpha2}
+
\frac{\sin^2\tfrac\alpha2}
{\frac{r_a}{b}\,\cos\tfrac\alpha2
 -(1-\sin\tfrac\alpha2)\,\sin\tfrac\alpha2}
=
1
\tag{5}\label{5},\\
\frac{1}
{\frac{r_a}{c}\,\cos\tfrac\alpha2
 -(1-\sin\tfrac\alpha2)\,\sin\tfrac\alpha2}
+
\frac{1}
{\frac{r_a}{b}\,\cos\tfrac\alpha2
 -(1-\sin\tfrac\alpha2)\,\sin\tfrac\alpha2}
=
\frac1{\sin^2\tfrac\alpha2}
\tag{6}\label{6},\\
.
\end{align}

This boils down to

\begin{align}
\sin^4\tfrac\alpha2-\sin^2\tfrac\alpha2
-
\frac{r_a^2}{bc}\,\cos^2\tfrac\alpha2
+\sin\tfrac\alpha2\,\cos\tfrac\alpha2
\left(\frac{r_a}{b}+\frac{r_a}{c}\right)
&=0
\tag{7}\label{7},\\
bc\,\sin^2\tfrac\alpha2\,(\sin^2\tfrac\alpha2-1)
-
r_a^2\,\cos^2\tfrac\alpha2
+\sin\tfrac\alpha2\,\cos\tfrac\alpha2
(r_a\,b+r_a\,c)
&=0
\tag{8}\label{8},\\
-bc\,\sin^2\tfrac\alpha2\,\cos\tfrac\alpha2
-
r_a^2\,\cos\tfrac\alpha2
+\sin\tfrac\alpha2\,
(r_a\,b+r_a\,c)
&=0
\tag{9}\label{9},\\
r_a\,(b+c)-bc\,\sin\tfrac\alpha2\,\cos\tfrac\alpha2-r_a^2\,\cot\tfrac\alpha2
&=0
\tag{10}\label{10},\\
r_a\,(b+c)-S-r_a^2\,\cot\tfrac\alpha2
&=0
\tag{11}\label{11},\\
r_a\,(b+c-r_a\,\cot\tfrac\alpha2)
&=S
\tag{12}\label{12},\\
2\,(b+c-r_a\,\cot\tfrac\alpha2)
&=-a+b+c
\tag{13}\label{13},\\
\tfrac12(a+b+c)
&=
r_a\,\cot\tfrac\alpha2
\tag{14}\label{14},\\
\tan\tfrac\alpha2
&\equiv
\frac{S}{\rho\,(\rho-a)}
\tag{15}\label{15}
,
\end{align}

which is a well-known identity.

Answer (score 2):

This is inversion proof (not projective!) with respect to circle which center is $M$ and $r= MD = ME$.

Let $FM$ cuts $DE$ at $T$. It is enough to show that $H$ halves $TE$.

Check this [link](https://www.geogebra.org/m/R8FSgfDg)

Since each $D$ and $E$ maps to it self, the circle $MDE$ maps to line $DE$ and so inversion swaps $K$ and $H$, where $K$ is intersection of line $MC$ and circle $MDE$. Also, this inversion swaps $F$ and $T$.

Since $\triangle CEK \sim \triangle CME \Longrightarrow \displaystyle{KE\over ME} = {CK\over CE} \;\;(1)$.

Similary  $\triangle CFK \sim \triangle CMF \Longrightarrow \displaystyle{KF\over MF} = {CK\over CF} \;\;(2)$.

Now remeber that if $X',Y'$ are images of $X,Y$ we have $$X'Y' = XY \cdot {r^2\over XM\cdot YM}$$

So $$ HE = KE \cdot {r^2\over KM\cdot EM} \stackrel{(1)}{=}{CK\over CE} \cdot {r^2\over KM}$$
and
So $$ HT = KF \cdot {r^2\over KM\cdot FM} \stackrel{(2)}{=}{CK\over CF} \cdot {r^2\over KM}$$

Since $CE = CF$ we have $HE= HT$. q.e.d.

Comment: I'm sure there is more elementary solution. I will try to find it

Comment: Seems that the link is still broken.

Answer (score 2):

Projective solution:

Let $t$ be a tangent in $M$. Then $t||DE$. Let $CM$ cuts segment $FE$ in $O$. Now we have:

\begin{eqnarray*}
  D(E,T;H, \infty) &=&  D(ME,MT;MH, M\infty)\\
   &=&  D(ME,MF;MK, MM)\\
   &=& D(E,F;K,M) \\
   &=& D(EE,EF;EK,EM) \\
   &=& D(EC,EO;EK,EM) \\
    &=& D(C,O;K,M) \\
&=&-1
\end{eqnarray*}
The last one is true since $O$ is on polar of $C$, so they are
harmonical conjugate.

So $H$ halves $ET$ since $D(E,T;H, \infty)=-1$. In the same manner we prove that $G$ halves $DT$ and we are done.

Comment: Somehow I can't find elementary solution. :(